# how to print certain row from specific file name that multiple appears under subdirectories

Tags: linux, shell

I got following file system

```
dir1/subDir1/index.html
dir1/subDir2/index.html
dir1/subDir3/index.html
```

index.hml contains tag [some text]

I want to print the tag row from all index.html instances
Something like this:

```
dir1/subDir1/index.html -> <name>[some text]</name>
dir1/subDir2/index.html -> <name>[some text]</name>
dir1/subDir3/index.html -> <name>[some text]</name>
```

Currently I use
cat */index.html |grep "name"

But I am getting only the tag list without subdirectories referral

Thanks

Comment: `grep "name" */index.html`?

Comment: @KamilCuk Bingo! Thanks

Comment: `find . -name index.html -exec grep name '{}' +`, or `grep name **/index.html` if using bash with the globstar option turned on, or zsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't give `grep` filenames he is not going to print them. So give it.

```
grep "name" */index.html
```